# Dynamic Use of Global Variable in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to utilize a global variable that I set by passing it in as an argument to a keyword but it is not working for some reason.  Here's the code:

```
*** Variables ***
${ENV}              qa
${MOBILE}           0
${BROWSER}          Chrome
${DELAY}            0
${VALID USER}       username
${VALID PASSWORD}   123456
&{SERVER}           qa=https://${PREFIX}.qa.myapp.com
...                 staging=https://${PREFIX}.staging.myapp.com
...                 prod=https://${PREFIX}.myapp.com
${LOGIN URL}        ${SERVER.${ENV}}/
${WELCOME URL}      ${SERVER.${ENV}}/Profile


*** Keywords ***
Begin Web Test
    [Arguments]   ${pf}
    [Tags]      Critical
    Set Global Variable  ${PREFIX}   ${pf}
    Open Browser    ${LOGIN URL}    ${BROWSER}
    Run Keyword If   ${MOBILE} == 1
    ...    Set Window Size    50  800
    ...    ELSE   Maximize Browser Window
    Set Selenium Speed    ${DELAY}
    Login Page Should Be Open
    Input Text    username    ${VALID USER}
    Input Text    password     ${VALID PASSWORD}
    Click Button  btn_login
    Location Should Be    ${WELCOME URL}
    Page Should Contain   Update Profile
```

When I run this I receive an error:

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/path/to/Common.robot': Setting variable '&{SERVER}' failed: Variable '${PREFIX}' not found.
```

Could someone explain why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables in the `*** Variables ***` section are static, and only set once prior to the start of the first test. You cannot expect the variables to automatically update when you change the value of `${PREFIX}`.

One solution would be to move the setting of the variables into a keyword that you can call either after defining the global variable, or by passing in the value of `${PREFIX}`.

Comment: Thanks for the proposed solution, that worked like a charm.